# Replace function on date Datatype-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a date datatype, which I want to change certain characters only  changing 1 to 9. like if the date is 1942-08-19 00:00:00.000 I want it to be change it as 9942-08-99 00:00:00.000'. I have tried this:

Please help.

Select would work but its the update that is not working and giving the error:

update table
  set [Birthdate]= Replace(Birthdate,'2','8')

Error: 'The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value'

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Most will allow you to `convert`/`cast` a date/datetime to a string, so that you can do that replace. Just make sure to convert the string back to datetime.

Comment: I had used cast as well but still Im getting 'The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value'. Im using SSMS 2017

Comment: Cast first then replace `REPLACE(CAST(Birthdate as varchar(50)),'1','9')` And just out of extreme curiousity.. why do you need to do this?

Comment: @AaronDietz nailed it. OP: Keep in mind, though, that if you're altering a date of December 31, 1925 (1925-12-31), and you're replacing "1" with "9" (or "2" with "8", as your question edit indicates), it would come out as `9925-92-39`, which is not a valid date.

Comment: Yes, I realized that now.. Any way thanks guys.. Even if I use replace it it wont work out for me.. But thanks for the help.

Comment: @Dibya if you're trying to __only__ update the year value, you can always work with the year `datepart` separately.

Answer (score 1):

For selecting data you can cast or convert:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CAST(Birthdate as varchar(50)),'1','9')
```

If you actually want to store that data, you will need to change your column datatype from `datetime` to a string type (ie. `varchar(50)`)

Or make another column to store the new string.

You can't store something like `9942-08-99 00:00:00.000` in a `datetime` column because that isn't a valid date.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to add a new column:

```
alter table t
    add birthdate_obfuscated as ( Replace(Birthdate, '2', '8') );
```

You cannot turn this back into a date, because the date (as in your example) may not be valid.

To be honest, I can't really think of a good reason for doing this.  If you want to confuse up the birthdates, you can choose a random date in the birth year.  If you want to randomize them, then you can add a random period of time to the date.